# getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with simple swift function

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to create a simple image filter. Here is a function, I've created:

```
func BlackandWhite(){
        for y in 0..<myRGBA.height {
            for x in 0..<myRGBA.width {
                let index2 = y * myRGBA.width + x
                var pixel = myRGBA.pixels[index2]
                let average = min((pixel.blue + pixel.red + pixel.green)/3, 250)
                pixel.blue = average
                pixel.red = average
                pixel.green = average
                myRGBA.pixels[index2] = pixel
            }
        }
        myRGBA.toUIImage()
 }
```

while running it gets error as in the title. I have no idea why.

Comment: it would be weird if it is beyond array bounds, because I have another, pretty similar function, which works properly. The differences between them start after that line: var pixel = myRGBA.pixels[index2]

Comment: What line is it on in the debugger when it crashes?